# Image is not displaying in my browser, it shows only alt value

Tags: html, image

```
<img src="fax.jpg" alt="icon" width="20" height="20">
```

Both the image and the file are in same directory.

The path to the file is:

`public_html/content/theme/data/file.php`

and the path to the image is:

`public_html/content/theme/data/image.jpg`

So, what is the issue? It only displays the `alt` value icon.

Comment: Post some code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess `public_html` is not seen by your browser as it's likely that the root directory starts there. Therefore the urls should start at `content`.

Comment: Use following way to display image: URL/content/theme/data/image.jpg public_html is for root path should not be used. Also dont use absolute directory path for image src

Answer (score 0):

change the `src` to the location of the image you would like to use, in your case `image.jpg`(and not `fax.jpg`)

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="icon" width="20" height="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this is occuring, you need to open up Chrome Inspector or Firefox Firebug and view the console, refresh the page and read what it tells you as to why the image is not loading. From what you've shown it seems that **image.jpg** is *not* **fax.jpg**, which would explain it.

Below are some common reasons that would cause this failure to connect, most won't apply to you but they'd be good for reference:

**1)** Check the spelling of you image file(s). Check that the file referenced in the `src=` part of the `<img>` tag exists and is the correct file name.

**2)** Check the cASe of your image file(s). Particularly if you're running this on a Linux/Apache server, which are case sensitive so `fax.jpg` and `Fax.jpg` are seen as different files.

**3)** Check that CHMOD (Permissions) of your image file(s), make sure they're accessible to the public. Typically at least `0644`.

**4)** If on an Apache server check if there is an  `.htaccess` file in the path structure (so, in any folder between `public_html` and the image file) that has any rules either rewriting the access or denying the access to the image file.

**5)** Check if your Content Security Policy is correctly configured to accept self as a reference, such as `img-src: 'self'` .

**6)** If your website is **https** but you're referencing files with an absolute URI using **http** then as a security measure most browsers will not show them by default.

**7)** The file is not a valid image/JPG file and can not be displayed by the browser because of this.

**8)** Hard refresh your browser with `CTRL` + `F5` to force it to check if content exists rather than using a possibly out-of-date cache.

---

But I go back to what I stated at the start, you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox or [Chrome Inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to get a solid reason why the image file does not show. That's the solution you should use. My list above is simply a list of maybes and I have no way of saying which is more -or less- likely.

Answer (score -1):

Give the full path to your image eg http://yoursite/content/theme/data/image.jpg

Don't use public html

Comment: sorry but this wouldn't solve the issue, if the image is in the same folder as the file calling it - as OP states - then the full path is just needless clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Path to image should be

```
$path = './image.jpg';
```

or if u using local path, u can fix it by that code

```
$path = str_replace("\\","/",html_entity_decode($path));
```

Comment: This would not solve the issue, as `./` prefix simply states the current directory and is implied by having no `./` at all. so `./fax.jpg` === `fax.jpg` in the HTML context.

Comment: *(also please try and use full words rather than text speak)*